# Need help to pivot one column into rows in SQL Server 2012 - no aggregates and no label column exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to get this

```
PatID   FacID   RxNo        RejectCd
121403  463     57074566    R9 
121403  463     57074566    76
121403  463     57074566    88
121403  463     57074566    8C
```

To look like this

```
PatID   FacID   RxNo        RejectCd
121403  463     57074566    R9,76,88,8c
```

Tried using a pivot or doing it in stages but I'm stuck. Can't pivot because I don't have a field for the column names. Also don't know how many Reject Codes will actually exist till it runs but we can ignore that part for now. I think this will be really challenging for any SQL nerds out there. Thank u!

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to [concatenate row values](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/), but one of the simplest and most common is using `for xml path('')`.

```
select
    PatId
  , FacId
  , RxNo
  , RejectCd = stuff(
      (
      select ',' + i.RejectCd
        from t as i
        where i.PatId = t.PatId
          and i.FacId = tFacId
          and i.RxNo  = t.RxNo
      for xml path (''), type).value('.','varchar(max)')
      ,1,1,'')
from t
group by 
    PatId
  , FacId
  , RxNo
```

in sql server vNext you will be able to use [**`string_agg()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt790580.aspx):

```
select 
    PatId
  , FacId
  , RxNo
  , RejectCd = string_agg (RejectCd, ',') 
      /* optional sort */ within group (order by RejectCd asc) 
from t 
group by 
    PatId
  , FacId
  , RxNo
```

Comment: Don't have the string_agg function so i used the first solution and it worked perfectly! Could not be more grateful! thank u! thank u! thank u!